# Could not locate Gemfile after executing "bundle install"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Hey,
I am completely new to Rails and just started created my first Project, following the Steps of a tutorial.

I created the new Project using: `rails myapp`.

Then I should execute `bundle install`, this did not work because bundler has not been installed, after an Update on Gems and installing bundler I have been able to execute `bundle install`, but every time I receive: Could not locate Gemfile

I checked my project dir, it is true there is no Gemfile, but should this be created automatically or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of rails did you use? Can you link to that tutorial if it's available online?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on your version of rails. Since you simply write `rails myapp` I assume you do not use Rails 3, where you would write `rails new myapp`. In Rails 3, at least, the `Gemfile` is created for you automatically, and I would recommend using the latest version of Rails.

Comment: Great, I just updated to 3.0.7 everything works fine. Thank you a lot.