# Unable to update rails version even by using gem update rails command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to build ROR application for which I wrote `rails fist_app` command in terminal. I didn't find `gemfile` in folder `fist_app`. When goggled, found [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896137/could-not-locate-gemfile-after-executing-bundle-install) for this problem which suggest to update rails.

But when I update rails version it shows nothing to update. Here is a screen-shot. [image]

Please suggest some solution for this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have rails installed as Ubuntu package, not as a gem, so you can't update it. Uninstall the rails package (`sudo apt-get remove rails`) and then install it again as a gem: `gem install rails`.

**UPDATE:** I'm not 100% sure it will work though, because `gem` is also installed as Ubuntu package. It's better to set up everything (ruby, gem and rails) through RVM. Here's a tutorial: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Comment: It works with the command gem install rails. The provided tutorial is awesome. Thanks

Comment: One more thing which differentiates rails old version and newer one is:- When you write a command for creating rails application, "rails new App" (1) In old version, it creates application named "new" whereas (2) newer version creates "App".